# Trying to implement Fast Fourier transform for vectors of length power of 2

Tags: fft, octave

If correctly done it is supposed to have running time O(n log n).

```
function d = ffTU(f)

n = [size(f)](1);

if n==1
  d = f;
  return;

else

  even=ffTU(f(2:2:end,:));
  odd =ffTU(f(1:2:end,:));

  for k=0:(n/2)-1
    T(k+1)= exp(-2i*pi*k/n)*odd(k+1);

  end

  for k=0:(n/2)-1
    d(k+1) = even(k+1) + T(k+1) + even(k+1) - T(k+1);
  end

end
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
error: ffTU: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
error: called from
    ffTU at line 16 column 11
```

I know that I have to adjust the indices of the functions but I think that I fixed that.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know about the built-in function [`fft`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), right?

Comment: Yes, but for exercise reasons I try to implement it by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preallocate `T` before the loop:

```
T = zeros(n/2,1);
```

Or better yet, compute it without the loop:

```
k = (0:(n/2)-1).';
T = exp(-2i*pi*k/n).*odd(:);
```

You should do similarly for `d`.

You also need to test that the input is even-sized.

Instead of

```
n = [size(f)](1);
```

do

```
n = size(f,1);
```

But if your input is not a column vector this goes bad. Fix it with

```
f = f(:);
n = size(f,1);
```

And there's an error in your computation of `d` because you set it to `2*even`, `T` is not used (as in `T-T==0`.